# Persisting not working when ManyToOne used with OneToMany thru relation table

Tags: java, hibernate, many-to-one, hibernate-onetomany

I have 3 entities User, Order, Item with a mapping like this:

```
@Entity
public class Item {
    @Id
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private long id; // item id predefined

    //..getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Client {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    private Long id;

    //...getters and setters
}

@Entity
public class Order {
    @Id
    @GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
    @Column(nullable = false)
    @Access(AccessType.PROPERTY)
    private Long id;

    @ManyToOne(optional = false, fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH
    })// without removing
    //@JoinColumn(name = "client_id") - works fine
    @JoinTable(name = "client_cr_order_cr_item",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "client_id"))
    private Client client;

    @NotEmpty
    @OneToMany(fetch = FetchType.LAZY, cascade = {
        CascadeType.PERSIST, CascadeType.MERGE,
        CascadeType.REFRESH, CascadeType.DETACH
    })// without removing
    @JoinTable(name = "client_cr_order_cr_item",
        joinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "order_id"),
        inverseJoinColumns = @JoinColumn(name = "item_id"))
    private List<Item> items;

    //...getters and setters
}
```

When I persist order it fails with error:

> ERROR: null value in column "item_id" violates not-null constraint

it generate query like this:

```
insert into client_cr_order_cr_item (client_id, order_id) values ()
```

i.e. it do not fill out segment_id field by some reason I don't know. But I refer to client not thru 3th table but using FK `@JoinColumn(name = "client_id")` , then it generate correct query:

```
insert into order_cr_item (order_id, item_id) values ()
```

Please, could you explain this behavior? Why mapping of client affect items? Is there any hint to make hibernate persists items to 3th table?

Comment: That might be a cascading/ordering problem, i.e. the join table is being written before the client id is generated. I can't tell you why that would happen right out of my head but ... since the relation is many-to-one why do you need a join-table? Why don't you just put the client_id column into your order table?

Comment: I don't want to order knows about client, let's assume for this example that order is reusable and maybe assigned to another entity, for example AnotherClient.

Comment: Well, your `Order` entity alreay knows about the client...

Comment: I meant on db level, I don't want there one extra column refer to client.

Comment: Do you expect that to happen or would you more likely end up in having added complexity that's not needed at all? Besides that since `Client` and `Order` are only loosely related I'd expect the client to already exist when the order is created. Thus you might think about changing your process: create the client first, then link it to the order. That would get rid your your problem as well :) - To solve your problem: did you check that Hibernate correctly creates the order and the client first, i.e. did you see the respective inserts?